# is there a boundary of visible area? [SceneKit iOS]

Tags: ios, ios8, scenekit

My problem is visible in this screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

The letter "M" and a ship is cut in half. When I changing the camera position I can see that it looks like invisible boundary "eating" my nodes.

Any ideas what could be done wrong?

Comment: You need to show us your code and explain your problem and what you've done so far to get help. Also insert your screenshots as images into the post rather than hyper-linking them somewhere else.

Comment: Agreed with Neku. I'd like to add the caveat that this looks like a clipping plane problem, but we cannot tell without more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does increasing the value of the zFar property of your camera help ?